# Go Lang mysql html comments

Tags: go, programming-languages

I would like to create a mysql form for comments and display them as well in html. 
I am able to use the MySQL package to read out data in the terminal but am struggling to output on the html/template engine any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to create dynamic webpages that have user input.  You are going to need to learn some HTML/CSS to make it look nice (Even if you do use templates you can find online).

In terms of generating the dynamic content, Golang provides a builtin templating library [http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/].  Or if you like, you can look into other templating languages like Mustache or Handlebars, which have libraries in Go if you want to go that route.

For collecting user input, you're going to want to create a form that POSTs the data to a particular endpoint of your server.  In making your server, I would look into both Golang's net/http package, which is fully featured, or you could look into Gorilla, another Go library that has a lot of nice features for making more powerful webapps and such.

A couple resources for you to check out:

https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/
http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have understanding to do this with php and html I'm just trying to translate over too go Lang for the submitting and rendering out from mysql. I will look at creating a simple go form using the template engine.